# How do i unit test in google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

After searching and even reading the documentation on app engine unit testing am still unable to make it work on my project.

The task is simple, I have my models and request handlers in main.py.
I have installed [gaetestbed](https://github.com/jgeewax/gaetestbed/) and included it on my test class.

My tests class looks like this;

```
from main import CloudDocument   # My model
class TestCloudDocument(DataStoreTestCase, unittest.TestCase):
    def test_find_document(self):
        self.assertEqual(CloudDocument.all().count(), 0)
```

When i run the above test it returns True yet my datastore has records, i would have expected this test to fail.

It seems like the test class does not see the datastore of my application. How can i make it
see and access my local datastore?

Gath

Comment: This is not the point of testing. In your `setUp` method on the test you can put your own test data in the datastore stub created for your test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unit tests run in an isolated environment, with their own local datastore. Only the records you add in your test or in your `setUp` function will be present.

Answer (score 1):

Shameless plug: if you'd like to load a lot of objects from within the setUp method, you can the [appengine-fixture-loader](https://github.com/rbanffy/appengine-fixture-loader) package

Answer (score 0):

I recommmend using ext.testbed([Local Unit Testing for Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/localunittesting)) instead of gaetestbed. As JJ (the maintainer of gaetestbed) noted, it is superceded by ext.testbed

If you do and you want to test an existing and populated datastore, you can do so with

```
 def init_datastore_v3_stub(self, enable=True, datastore_file=None,
                             use_sqlite=False, **stub_kw_args):
    """Enable the datastore stub.

    The 'datastore_file' argument can be the path to an existing
    datastore file, or None (default) to use an in-memory datastore
    that is initially empty.  If you use the sqlite stub and have
    'datastore_file' defined, changes you apply in a test will be
    written to the file.  If you use the default datastore stub,
    changes are _not_ saved to disk unless you set save_changes=True.

    Note that you can only access those entities of the datastore file
    which have the same application ID associated with them as the
    test run. You can change the application ID for a test with
    setup_env().

    Args:
      enable: True if the fake service should be enabled, False if real
        service should be disabled.
      datastore_file: Filename of a dev_appserver datastore file.
      use_sqlite: True to use the Sqlite stub, False (default) for file stub.
      stub_kw_args: Keyword arguments passed on to the service stub.
    """
```

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/testbed/__init__.py#431